In Odoo 13, how can I get my custom module to load after an oca_addon?
I have Odoo 13 set up with an oca_addons directory and also another directory for my custom module.
The oca_addons includes mail_quoted_reply. There are a few other oca_addons installed as well.
I want to modify one of the functions in mail_message_reply.js
However I can't get it to work as no matter what I try it looks like the oca_addon, or at least the javascript file, is being loaded after mine, essentially overriding the changes I make because the original JavaScript function is being called instead of my inherited one.
What I have tried:

In my module's manifest, include 'mail_quoted_reply' in depends to force it to load before my module.
Create a separate assets template and set priority="1" to try and force it to take priority.

EDIT - Added JavaScript file.
odoo.define("my_module.mail_message_reply_override", function (require) {
"use strict";

const MailThread = require('mail.widget.Thread');

MailThread.include({
    events: _.extend({}, MailThread.prototype.events, {
        "click .o_thread_mail_message_reply": "_onClickMailMessageReply",
    }),
    _onClickMailMessageReply: function (event) {
        console.log("This never prints")
    },
});


please post code of your js file

Edited to include JavaScript file.

how about writing your modif directly inside the oca module?

Yes that does indeed work, but was under the impression this is bad practice?

yes, Not the best practice, but no danger neither, just take note of your customization, in case that you install a higher version (v17...) of this oca module in the future
